# android build error Failed linking resources

Tags: android, android-studio

I uninstalled a previous version of android and just have install version3.0.1 I created a new application in android studio scratch I have not modified any code but when I try to build the project I get the following errors

```
Error:resource style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar (aka com.example.android.my:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar) not found.
C:\AndroidStudioProjects\MyAPP\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml
Error:(101) error: style attribute 'attr/colorPrimary (aka com.example.android.my:attr/colorPrimary)' not found.
Error:(102) error: style attribute 'attr/colorPrimaryDark (aka com.example.android.com.example.android.my:attr/colorPrimaryDark)' not found.
Error:(103) error: style attribute 'attr/colorAccent (aka com.example.android.my:attr/colorAccent)' not found.
Error:(101) style attribute 'attr/colorPrimary (aka com.example.android.my:attr/colorPrimary)' not found.
Error:(102) style attribute 'attr/colorPrimaryDark (aka com.example.android.my:attr/colorPrimaryDark)' not found.
Error:(103) style attribute 'attr/colorAccent (aka com.example.android.my:attr/colorAccent)' not found.
Error:failed linking references.
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt
```

This is my `build.gradle` file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.android.my"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
   "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
  buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'p 
        roguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

 dependencies {
   implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
   implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
   testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
   androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
   androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
  core:3.0.1'
 }
```

And this is my `values.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<attr format="reference" name="constraintSet"/>
<attr format="integer" name="layout_constraintBaseline_creator"/>
  ..... some codes here ....
 <attr format="dimension" name="layout_goneMarginTop"/>
 <attr name="layout_optimizationLevel">
     <flag name="none" value="1"/>
     <flag name="all" value="2"/>
     <flag name="basic" value="4"/>
     <flag name="chains" value="8"/>
 </attr>
 <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
 <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
 <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
  <declare-styleable name="ConstraintLayout_Layout"><attr name="android:orientation"/><attr name="android:minWidth"/>
  .... some more attributes here ....

<string name="app_name">MyAppName</string>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
      <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
      <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
       <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
       <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
   </style>
</resources>
```

It seems that that error are some strange behaviors in android studio I have invalidated caches and restarted the project but the issue still exists, 
How should I solve this issue?

Answer (score 8):

If anyone reading this has the same problem, this happened to me recently, and it was due to having the xml header written twice by mistake:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <!-- Remove this one -->
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <solid android:color="@color/mug_blue"/>
     <corners android:radius="@dimen/featured_radius" />
</shape>
```

The error I was getting was completely unrelated to this file so it was a tough one to find. Just make sure all your new xml files don't have some kind of mistake like this (as it doesn't show up as an error).

Comment: Worked Like Charm for me. Thanks @P Fuster

Comment: Hi, @HimanshuRawat actually you should do the changes in your project, not here in the question :D

Answer (score 4):

you have duplicated lines in your gradle file. the fallowings are same

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
```

---

**remove following line:**

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
```

Comment: try using  " clean"  then  " rebuild "  command from android studio menu

Comment: your minSdkVersion is 21 can you use `Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar` in `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">`

Answer (score 2):

I was receiving this error when doing the [android tutorial on support libraries](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-training-support-libraries/index.html?index=..%2F..android-training#5)

The problem is in your styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
      **<!-- Customize your theme here. -->
      <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
       <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
       <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>**
</style>
```

Just remove those 4 item lines above and it will work.
Perhaps because you are using a Compat library and the theme is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change anything in dependencies. If you are combining multi-module, maybe they are conflicted , you must add prefix "android:". In this situation, I think you just update your file styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

It's worked with my source.